# SQL client seems to be using random port to connect

Tags: sql-server

Sorry if this is not the place to ask, but I am not sure if there is a forum for SQL port questions. It seems that my SQL client is using a random port to connect to the SQL server, in spite of me stipulating a specific port in the ODBC DSN connector. [this is from Microsoft Network Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBI6Q.jpg) I have included the image to better illustrate what I mean.

Comment: See [Configure a Server to Listen on a Specific TCP Port (SQL Server Configuration Manager)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177440.aspx).

Comment: Hi TT, thank you, yes I have done that, but if you look at the image you will see that the source port and the destination port are different. Is this normal or am I missing something on the client (WEBSERVER) side? The alias on the client side is there, in the cliconfg.exe alias option.

Comment: Oh right, apologies. So you are seeing that the client-side uses a different port each time. Can you include a code-fragment in your question that shows how you are connecting to SQL Server (blank out the password). Also, when editing please include all relevant tags pertaining to technologies used (eg C++, ODBC, etc). You can edit your question by clicking `edit` link below your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading it wrong. I see two kinds of connections, from `WEBSERVER` to `192.*.6` which I assume to be the Sql Server (the requests), and vice versa (the responses from Sql back to the Web Server).

When `WEBSERVER` is making a request, the `DstPort` is always 49252. The `SrcPort` fluctuates in that case because that is just how TCP/IP works (and that is also how multiple parallel connections can be distinguished). The Sql Server then always replies to whatever port number initiated the request.

Comment: Ah OK, thank you Peter. I appreciate the prompt response.

Answer (score 1):

It is expected that the source port (client) be random.  The destination port (server) will be constant.  When a TCP/IP client connects, it chooses an unused client port and connects to the server listening on a known port.  This is basically how TCP/IP sockets work.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies!!! Still have a lot learn re TCP, evidently.